# Pandas mean across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe which I created using numpy arrays (MnthIdx, Val1, Val2, Val3) as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfout3 = pd.DataFrame({'Idx': MnthIdx,
                       'Col1': Val1,
                       'Col2': Val2,
                       'Col3': Val3)})

MeanTable1 = pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Val1'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
MeanVal1 = np.asarray(MeanTable1['mean'])
MeanTable2 = pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Val2'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
MeanVal2 = np.asarray(MeanTable2['mean'])
MeanTable2 = pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Val3'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
MeanVal3 = np.asarray(MeanTable3['mean'])
```

Is it possible that I can do the above 3 steps in 1 steps only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with 3 columns as parameter `values`. `Aggfunc=[np.mean]` can be omited, because this is default aggregating function. Last if need output as `numpy array`, use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
print (pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']))
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

MnthIdx = [1,2,2,3,3]
Val1 =    [2,5,2,3,4]
Val2 =    [6,1,5,3,5]
Val3 =    [3,9,5,7,8]


dfout3 = pd.DataFrame({'Idx': MnthIdx,
                       'Col1': Val1,
                       'Col2': Val2,
                       'Col3': Val3})

MeanTable1 = pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Col1'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
MeanVal1 = np.asarray(MeanTable1['mean'])
MeanTable2 = pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Col2'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
MeanVal2 = np.asarray(MeanTable2['mean'])
MeanTable3 = pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Col3'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
MeanVal3 = np.asarray(MeanTable3['mean'])
```

```
print (MeanTable1)
    mean
    Col1
Idx     
1    2.0
2    3.5
3    3.5

print (MeanTable2)
    mean
    Col2
Idx     
1      6
2      3
3      4

print (MeanTable3)
    mean
    Col3
Idx     
1    3.0
2    7.0
3    7.5

print (pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']))
     Col1  Col2  Col3
Idx                  
1     2.0   6.0   3.0
2     3.5   3.0   7.0
3     3.5   4.0   7.5

print (pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']).values)
[[ 2.   6.   3. ]
 [ 3.5  3.   7. ]
 [ 3.5  4.   7.5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Working off jezael answer:

```
df    = pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
means = [ np.asarray(df[x]) for x in list(df)]
'MeanTable1','MeanTable2','MeanTable3' = means
```

or

```
(MeanTable1,MeanTable2,MeanTable3) = [ np.asarray(df[x]) for x in list(df)]
```

This would get you the means as arrays.